# Minimal polynomial of $i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm looking for the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. A polynomial with a root $\alpha$ is

$$(2(x-\frac{1}{2}))^4-9.$$

A computer algebra system shows me that the polynomial is irreducible. I looking for a way to compute this by hand in an exam. Is there any way to do so without using any irreduciblity criterions which where not part of my lecture?

Comment: First of all, it is not monic so it is not the minimal polynomial. Second, how, in your lectures, polynomials of degree $>3$ were shown to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ without  irreduciblity criterions ?

Comment: btw: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%28x-\frac{1}{2}%29%29^4-9 shows a decomposition into two polynomials of degree $2$

Comment: The polynomial is a difference of squares, so it is immediately obvious that it factors- I point this out as a general technique: it factors as $[4(x-\frac{1}{2})^{2} - 3][4(x-\frac{1}{2})^{2} +3],$ and each of these quadratic factors is in $\mathbb{Q}[x].$

Comment: @Joachim: The question may be relevant to others sometime in the future, this is why users lose the ability to delete questions after an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  $x=i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\implies 2x-1=i\sqrt3\implies x^2-x+1=0 $  is the minimal polynomial with integral coefficients.

Another way to address this is to put $i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=R(\cos y+i\sin y)=Re^{iy}$ where $R$ is a positive real number.

Squaring & adding we get , $R^2=1\implies R=1$

So, $\cos y=\frac{1}{2}$ and  $\sin y=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$  $\implies \tan y=\sqrt3$

As the cosine and sine ratios of $y$ are positive, so $y=\frac{\pi}{3}$

So, $x=i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

To rationalize $e^{\frac{ip\pi}{q}}$ where $p,q$ are integers with (p,q)=1, we need to take the q-th power as $e^{ip\pi}=(-1)^p$

So $x^3=-1\implies x^3+1=0$, but clearly,$x≠-1$

So, $\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}=0\implies x^2-x+1=0$

Comment: This polynomial is not monic

Comment: Why monic polynomial is required at all? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Due to the definition of minimal polynomial to make it unique.

Comment: I'll first need to ask you if you think the minimal polynomial is unique ? (the *definition* I know for minimal polynomial requires it to be monic, as a side product it is also unique by this definition)

Comment: They ARE different as polynomials...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)  and  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicNumberMinimalPolynomial.html  confirms your point, thanks.

Comment: The keyword here is *monic associate*. There are many (infinitely many over \Bbb{Q}) [associates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)#Definition) for any polynomial $f(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: The gist of the matter seems to be the word "the": **THE** minimal polynomial, within this context, seems to be almost universally defined, at least in the more modern textbooks, as the monic one. *A* minimal polynomial is defined just up to a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this by thinking geometrically - from trigonometry, you might remember that $$e^{i \pi/3} = \frac{1}{2}+ i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} .$$  Therefore, this is a zero of $x^3 +1$.  A quick check shows that this is not irreducible, since $-1$ is a root.  Therefore we can factor it:  $x^3 + 1 = (x -1)(x^2 - x + 1)$.  Thus $ \frac{1}{2}+ i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $ is a root of $x^2 - x + 1$.  The minimal polynomial must have degree $\geq 2$ since $ \frac{1}{2}+ i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}. $   Therefore $x^2 -x +1$ must be the minimal polynomial.  Alternately, you can check directly that $x^2 -x +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it is degree 2 and its roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}$.